# How do I configure GRUB and Ubuntu Server to boot to console by default with GUI option?

Tags: ubuntu, grub

I am running Ubuntu Server 11.04 in VirtualBox as a development server.  After install, because I'm new to Ubuntu, I added the Unity desktop to help me finish configuring everything.  Now, I would like the machine to default boot into the console, as it normally does for Ubuntu Server.  But I would also like a GRUB entry option to boot into the GUI if I so desire.  How can I accomplish this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a GRUB entry to boot into the CLI, and *also* a GRUB entry to boot the same partition, but start X?

Far simpler: remove your display manager (by default, I believe gdm3) or disable it. This will cause Ubuntu to boot into the CLI. Then if you need the GUI just type "startx &" at any console.